What is the rate of increase in magnitude of a sorted list of factors of a large integer
I understand that the Hardy-Ramanujan theorum shows that a very large integer $n$ will on average have about $log(log(n))$ distinct factors. What I am interested in is how the magitude of the factors grows - i.e. if the $m ~= log(log(n))$ factors of $n$ are sorted by size into a list ${p_1<p_2<p_3<.....<p_m}$, what is the average rate of growth of the factors? More specifically, how does $p_i$ increase with $i$, as $i$ approaches $m$.
